# Get querySelector All multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I'd like to get all a Elements which got contain the classes `menu-item-link` and `mk-image-link`. Is the following expression right?

```
a[class*="menu-item-link"], a[class*="mk-image-link"]
```

Didn't get anything selected so I guess not :)

Thanks for the help.

Best regards, 
Anton

Comment: There's no way the selector string you have didn't return any elements. (Besides, is there a reason you're using attribute selectors and not class selectors like a normal person would do?)

Answer (score 4):

You have to do this `'a.menu-item-link, a.mk-image-link'` it will check if a has this class.

```js
const selected = document.querySelectorAll('a.menu-item-link, a.mk-image-link')
const selected2 = document.querySelectorAll('a.menu-item-link.js-smooth-scroll, a.mk-image-link.js-smooth-scroll')

console.log(selected)
console.log(selected2)
```

```html
<div class="menu-item-link"><div>
<div><div>
<a class="menu-item-link"></a>
<a class="mk-image-link"></a>
<a class="mk-image-link menu-item-link"></a>
<a class="menu-item-link js-smooth-scroll" href="/superfood-rezepte/">SUPERFOOD REZEPTE</a> <a href="...." target="_self" class="mk-image-link">
```

Comment: Thanks @Maciej Kozieja: How would it look like if menu-item-link is just a part of 'menu-item-link js-smooth-scroll'. So I want to select everthing that contains 'menu-item-link'. Do I have to work with wildcard?

Comment: @Toni2708 Give examle html in question

Comment: <a class="menu-item-link js-smooth-scroll" href="/superfood-rezepte/">SUPERFOOD REZEPTE</a>

<a href="...." target="_self" class="mk-image-link">

Comment: so it will be `a.menu-item-link.js-smooth-scroll, a.mk-image-link`?

Comment: Thanks right, but what if the part .js-smooth-scroll changes dynamically? I already found out how to do this with one selector a[class*="menu-item-link"]. The same thing I want to do with another selector and join them togehter in just one QuerySlector all statement like in the first example.

Comment: If it changes dynamicly then you can't select it that way because in this moment it could not has class you want

Answer (score 1):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) allows grouping of selectors.

Note that, it would select all elements which has the specified `class names`, so a wild-card is not needed. i.e. if you are aiming at `menu-item-link` and `mk-image-link` the below should work for you.

So, you could try the below:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[class~='menu-item-link'], a[class~='mk-image-link']"); // OR 
elements = document.querySelectorAll("a.menu-item-link, a.mk-image-link"); // Would both selects the same
elements.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
});
```

```html
<a class="js menu-item-link js-smooth-scroll" href="/superfood-rezepte/">SUPERFOOD REZEPTE</a> <br>
<a class="js menu-item-link js-smooth-scroll-a" href="/superfood-rezepte/">SUPERFOOD </a> <br>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_self" class="mk-image-link">Something</a>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_self" class="mk-image-link1">Another Something</a>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_self" class="mk-image-link js-smooth-scroll-b">Another Something</a>
```

Comment: Thanks worked now!